# Joomla - saved failed with the following error super user

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

```
Error
Save failed with the following error:
```

I am getting the above error while saving an article. It occurs on few articles and not all.

As part of the context to this problem. I migrated all articles from a joomla 1.5 installation to a joomla 3.x installation. In the 1.5 installation, everything works fine but after migration, only few articles seem like that .. It doesn't say what the error is else I'd be able to figure it out.

Can someone help me diagnose this problem.

UPDATE: Just happens with two categories and not others.

### UPDATE 2: Better Explanation

Articles in uncategorized works correctly. No problems there.
As soon as I put these articles in a new category or existing category where it should actually be, it gets saved there but then the above error comes up.. viz. 'Save failed with the following error:' but it doesn't mention what error. Any modification gets saved without an issue as per my latest understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a permission error with the ACL system in Joomla 3.x.

You could try to create two NEW categories and then **copy** their articles in the new categories. Finally delete the OLD categories and renamed the NEW ones.

My assumption is that the ACL tree got messed up and hopefully creating a new category and deleting the old one will reset the tree for those categories.

**UPDATE 2: Content plugins**

OK, another thing you may want to try is to disable all your *content* plugins. One of them may be doing something that triggers the display of that error.

Comment: I tried creating as you suggested but I still face the same issue. Let me illustrate in a better way. Do check my update.

Comment: I see. Then check your content plugins as per my update.

Comment: No, don't copy MOVE. If you copy it will create second set and destroy your urls and any links. I agree that most likely the assets tree is messed up, and you can either fix that by carefully moving and moving back or by using assetFix.